# Citroen Xsara - Worked this morning, now won't start

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, ignition, citroen

I drove my Xsara early this morning, got back in 2-3 hours later and NOTHING!!

Dash lights, headlights, etc. are fine – so battery has power.

What could be the issue to happen so suddenly and are there any quick fixes till I can get it to a mechanic? Unless its just a loose wire or fuse, then I'll do it myself.

Comment: Did you try giggling the keys in the ignition while turning the keys? My first inclination in a situation like this is the ignition system is having an issue. You could try turning the key several times in quick succession and see if you get anything out of it. Also, are there any blinking lights on the dash which look like a lock or security key?

Comment: What do you mean by "NOTHING?" Does the engine crank and fail to start, or does it not crank, or is it something else?